# Replace Epson LQ 2190 with Software Capture

Tags: javascript, c#, python, epson, escpos

We are facing some issue in my place. My Printer is not working anymore. So i need to replace those with software.

IS there any code available in any language to decode esc/pos to readble format ?

My setup :

1.Create local/nw TCP printer on local machine with EPSON LQ 2190 as printer driver.

2. And In remote i have captured those data with TCP listener.
3. Next step id decoding those. but how ?

Comment: These might be helpful. [QPCPrint](https://www.kilgus.net/qpcprint/), [Epson ESC/P2 printer emulation tools](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/epson-esc-p2-printer-emulation-tools-4175552916/), [Support & Downloads: PLQ-20D](https://www.epson.de/en/viewcon/corporatesite/products/mainunits/faq/2084/8348)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But those are referring to sending data to ESC/P2 printers. But i have to replace printer with software.

Comment: is any solution available